# Video Play On specific Time and Date site

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to play video on my site on predefined time and date. I have the site and video is uploaded. Now i want this video to be played on specific time, let suppose i have given the time and date like 27 December 2012, 5PM. It must play on 27 December 2012, 5pm.

Please let me know how to implement this in javascript or php.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what is your code for playing video. If you post that, I might help you with Javascript

Comment: Just use `setTimeout()` for that on your page; at each page load, calculate the time until timestamp. Alternatively, let PHP calculate the time until.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own code and if you encounter any problems comeback here and ask for help on how to solve it. 
Otherwise, this is the only help I can spare you.

```
if(date() === "1234567890"){

//play the freaking video. 

}
```

Plus, if user has disabled Javascript, then how do they get to see your video?

Comment: The likelihood that the expression is true is pretty low for time sensitive expressions, you should always add a greater than.

Comment: that for advice. @Jack But, I was chatting a while ago, and was told actually the action can be excecuted if the page is leaded during the excat time the condition is made

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Don't know why you're using date() either.

Comment: I meant that for the code to work, or for the video to be played in this case, the browser must run (be opened/refreshed) in the exact minute and second of the specified time

Comment: Well, that greatly reduces the usefulness of this answer doesn't it? :)

Answer (score 0):

If the timestamp is known to PHP, you can simply calculate the time remaining:

```
$ts = strtotime('2012-12-31 23:59:59');
$time_until = max(0, $ts - time()); // make sure it doesn't become negative.

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout('showVideo', <?php echo $time_until; ?> * 1000);
</script>
```

In this case I let JavaScript do the multiplication because PHP isn't very good at it for large numbers; it all depends on how big you think `$time_until` is going to be :)